# ¿Como se podrá hacer una app que se actualice automáticamente sin PlayStore en Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy realizando una app en android studio y firebase para ser específico un chat pero no tengo intención de subirla a la play store y quiero implementar que se actualice automáticamente, buscando por Youtube encontré este video que es justo lo que pienso https://youtu.be/FjWh8Xphwkc y lo realice si me válida la versión que tiene la app con la que tengo en firebase y si se descarga la app pero no la instala creo suponer que por la versión de android que ocupo en el vídeo que es 6 y en mi caso mi teléfono ocupa android 10 no permite que se instale :( 
principalmente lo que me falla es esta parte

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)){
                intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int ColumIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(ColumIndex)) {
                        String uriString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        File file = new File(uriString);
                        System.out.print(file);
                        Intent prompInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        prompInstall.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(uriString)));
                        //
                        prompInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        prompInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        prompInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        prompInstall.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                         //
                        prompInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uriString), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        startActivity(prompInstall);
                        System.out.println("apk descargado");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    MessageActivity.this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

en logcat me sale el error que "startActivity(prompInstall);" no encuentra una activity por que es nulo 
en el manifest coloque tambien esto

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

por que encontre un hilo donde se no se ocupa action_view sino action_install_PACKAGE en esta linea

```
Intent prompInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

al final si descarga el apk del storage del firebase pero no lo instala y me cierra la aplicación

Comment: por favor añade el còdigo estas tratando, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: si gracias Jorgesys ya implemente la parte del codigo, saludos :)